# How to add multiple Annotations or Pins in MapView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am developing an application which locates the current user location and displays the nearest sport centers to the user's current location. 
At the moment I am adding the latitude and longitude manually into the `viewDidLoad()`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    let pinLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.0757,25.6172)
    let objectAnn = MKPointAnnotation()
    objectAnn.coordinate = pinLocation
    objectAnn.title = "Fitnes"
    objectAnn.subtitle = "Power"
    self.MapView.addAnnotation(objectAnn)

    let pinLocation2: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.0657,25.6272)
    let objectAnn2 = MKPointAnnotation()
    objectAnn2.coordinate = pinLocation2
    objectAnn2.title = "Swimming Pool"
    objectAnn2.subtitle = "Aqua"
    self.MapView.addAnnotation(objectAnn2)
}
```

Is it possible to save the latitude and longitude coordinates in a JSON file and when the user opens the app, they are uploaded automatically into the function?

Also is it possible out of the coordinations the application to calculate the distance, so that the user is able to set a (km) range and see only these places which are near him?

I would be glad if you provide me with an simple code.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> Is it possible to save the latitude and longitude coordinates in a JSON file and when the user opens the app, they are uploaded automatically into the function?

Yes, build a dictionary with the latitude and longitude values and then use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert back and forth between that dictionary and a `NSData` that can be saved to (and read from) a file. If this is just for your own purposes, you can also read and write `NSDictionary` values directly to a file, without needing JSON. JSON is excellent, though, if you're going to be sending and receiving this data with external resources, such as a web service.

> Also is it possible out of the coordinations the application to calculate the distance, so that the user is able to set a (km) range and see only these places which are near him?

Sure, create `CLLocation` objects from the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` values. And then you can use `distanceFromLocation` to calculate the distance between two `CLLocation` objects.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response. I am beginner in developing swift application. Can you show me a sample code or example which I can learn or use for my project.

Comment: I'd encourage you to give it a go yourself, and if you have any problems, edit your question to include code samples, describing what happened and what you expected. I've tried to give you enough pointers to get you going in the right direction...

Comment: I appreciate it, but I am afraid to admit that tI do not have a clue how to use the pointers you sent me.